# Get app's ID number from iTunes URL string

Tags: ios, regex, string, swift

I need to find a way to parse an app's ID number from an iTunes URL. For example, this URL -

https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/mouse-times-florida/id1021402097?mt=8

Would give me this - 1021402097

I was considering different ways to do this with string splitting and such, but they all seem kind of hacky. I suppose I could just split the string after 'id' and end the split after 10 digits, but there's a risk that IDs could be increased to 11 digits in the future.

Anyone have a better idea using regex or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can make the following assumptions:

- The id will only contain digits.
- The number of digits, which currently is 10, will only grow.
- In the url, the `id...` part contains the id.

Then, you can use a simple regex such as this: `id([\d]{10,})`, in which your id will be captured in group 1. Working example: https://regex101.com/r/nD0mZ8/1

Comment: I like that your solution factors in organic growth of the substring size.

Comment: You cannot assume a minimum length of 10.  For example https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/minecraft-pocket-edition/id479516143?mt=8 has 9.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use regular expressions or do any fancy parsing. Put the URL in an `NSURL`. Then get the `lastPathComponent` of the `NSURL`. That will give you the `id1021402097` part.

Now simply get the substring starting from index 2 and you will have `1021402097`.

```
let url = NSURL(string:"https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/mouse-times-florida/id1021402097?mt=8")
let idStr = url!.lastPathComponent!
let appId = idStr.substringFromIndex(idStr.startIndex.advancedBy(2))
```

I'm not fluent in Swift so you need to deal with the optionals properly.